# custom object with button linking back to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have view controller and a custom object that will return a view with buttons. I to set the button's target to a method on the view controller. I just want this object to create the view i want and then return it for me to `addSubview:`.

```
CreateView.m

//create button
[button addTarget:(view controller) action:@selector(buttonMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How can i do this? Pass the view controller's self to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so CreateView is basically a factory responsible for creating views?
then yes, pass the pointer to the viewController to the method.

e.g.

```
@interface CreateView : NSObject {
}
+ (UIView*)createViewFor:(id)target;
@end
```

Comment: Yes, it would just be a factory. I don't see any clear advantage in the view class with delegates over doing it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this. It may help you for solve this issue.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonMethod:(id)sender
{
  CreateView *c=[CreateView alloc]initWithNibName:@"CreateView" bundle:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:c.view];
}
```

Comment: he didn't ask how to get the action to the button and then add it to CreateView: CreateView isnt even a view, it is a factory producing views :)